# fun with symlink and buffers

Tags: buffers, plugin-fugitive

I have a funny problem.

I have the following symlink in /Users/eyalkarni/ AKA ~

```
.vimrc -> /Users/eyalkarni/vimpy3/.vimrc
```

vimpy3 is a git repository.

I opened  ~/.vimrc in neovim and now I can't use git-fugitive because it doesn't know it is inside git repo.

So, naturally, I tried `:bd` and going into ~/vimpy3 and open it from there.

It didn't work either. It keeps calling it ~/.vimrc , thinking it is in ~.

I guess `:bw` will work, but I also have some marks in the file that I don't want to lose.

How to overcome this?

Comment: I thought about going to the cache file of neovim (where it keeps the marks) and changing the name of the buffer. Couldn't find it.

Comment: Check `:h :0file` and `:h :file_f`

Comment: You can post this as an answer

Comment: I didn't post it as answer cz I don't know if it will work. Vim-fugitive might only initialize when you open a file, and in that case, changing the filename isn't gonna do you any favor. I just wanted you to know that there is a process to change the filename associated with the current buffer. If the process worked, you can post an answer yourself; or let me know that it worked and I'll post the answer.

Comment: It worked. Just had to do :file using the full path and then `e` to reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how vim-fugitive checks if the current file is under a git repository, but for this specific case you can follow the following steps to get the job done:

```
:file <path/to/file>
:edit
```

Here, `:file <path/to/file>` changes the associated file of the current buffer to the provided file and `:edit` reloads the current buffer. A buffer is the in-memory text of a file. So, what you see on the window/split is actually a buffered memory (hence the name `buffer`). When you do `:write`, you save the current buffered memory to the associated file and when you do `:edit`, you reload the current buffered memory with the content of the associated file. So, when you do `:file <path/to/file>` you change the associated file of the current buffer and henceforward do any interaction with that file.

Now, when you changed the associated file and reloaded it, the buffer checked that it's in a git repository and launched vim-fugitive instance; or so I conjecture since I already got the confirmation that this  solution worked from the OP.

Check out `:h file_f` for more information.